# Not able to print the child table values in bootstarap bootgrid

Tags: jquery-bootgrid

JSON response:

```
{
    "current": 1,
    "rowCount": 10,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "sender": "123@test.de",
            "received":"[
        {
            "name":"received1"
        }
    ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 14,
    "sender": "123@test.de",
    "received":  [
        {
            "name":"received2"
        }
    ]
},
    ...],
"total": 1123}
```

I want to print the received name using bootgrid.

Example:

```
<th data-column-id="id" data-identifier="true">Id</th>
<th data-column-id="received.name">Name</th>
```

I am able to print `received.name`, but not able to print `id`.

Comment: Firstly, make sure your json is correct.

Comment: The JSON you provided is invalid. Please check.

Comment: Its edited problem :P , now i have changed it. And also i posted the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the above issue we have to use data-formatter in bootstrap bootgrid.

i have attached the code here, hope it will helpful.

```
<script>  $("#MyTable").bootgrid({
            ajax: true,formatters: {
                "link": function (column, row) 
                {
                    return "<span>" + row.received.name+ "</span>";
                }
            }}); 
</script>
```

Your Html will like

```
 <table>
 <th data-column-id="received.name" data-formatter="link">Anything</th> 
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "current": 1,
    "rowCount": 10,
"total": 123
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 19,
            "sender": "123@test.de",
            "received":"received1"
        },
{
            "id": 20,
            "sender": "123@testasdasd.de",
            "received":"receisaddved1"
        }
]
}
```

// This is the way to populate the grid my friend.